# Applying for residence permit in Germany with type D visa

Tags: germany, study, residency

I am an exchange student in Germany, with a type D visa for the length of the semester (around 5 months), however, I was offered an internship as well as I am applying for an intensive Germany course for the period of 7 months. I went to the Foreigners Office and they told me it is possible to apply for a residence permit if I provide them with a proof from the deutschkurse or the internship, proof of accommodation, and proof of subsistence. However, a friend of mine just came back from the same Foreigners' Office asking for the same thing and they told him that he would have to go back to our country of origin (Egypt) and then reapply for a new visa? I am a little worried now and I would like to know if I can actually get a residence permit in this condition or not? I have to decide soon.

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: @phoog Egyptian

Comment: @phoog says Egypt in the text

Comment: http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/__16.html 

I have came across this link while searching for an answer, however, my german isn't that good yet! can someone infer from it, whether I can get a residence permit or not? I came as an exchange student, can I get a residence permit for another purpose or not?

Comment: @blackbird57 oops, I overlooked "our" so I thought that only the friend was Egyptian.

Answer (score 1):

More of a comment, but I need space to quote.

§16(2)1 says

> Während des Aufenthalts nach Absatz 1 oder 1a soll in der Regel keine Aufenthaltserlaubnis für einen anderen Aufenthaltszweck erteilt oder verlängert werden, sofern nicht ein gesetzlicher Anspruch besteht.

That means roughly

> During a stay in accordance with section 1 or 1a generally another stay for another purpose shall not be given or extended unless there is a legal requirement.

Under which section did you get your initial student visa, and is the internship legally considered a paid job?

Comment: I got my visa as an exchange student for this winter semester, now what I want to do is to get a residence permit to study deutsch intensively, to be able to apply for a german university, so is this considered as a "different purpose" or also considered as educational purpose? I do not know about the legal aspect of the internship really, and frankly I can drop it if it might make problems. I only care about deutsch, it would have just been a side research nothing more.

Comment: Also would you think it differs, if I take the intensive course in a private sprachschule or if I somehow managed to get admitted in a university for a summer semester and take language preparatory courses there?

Comment: The meaning of Praktikum (internship) ranges from a mandatory part of university courses to paid and insured entry-level jobs. No way to tell without more details. Have you considered talking to a lawyer? That'll cost you some, but it will be professional and specific advice. Or the student's organization at the university (AStA, Studentenwerk) might help.